# Where to save API logs in a nodejs application?

Tags: mysql, node.js, npm, web-applications

I'm using `express` framework for my node application and using `REST API` to interaction.

Need to save and maintain logs for API Request and response, including some other fields too like `success` response, `error` response and API `end-point`.

What's best way to save logs, in a `logger.log` file or database?

Using `simple-node-logger` which automatically save logs in a file, or is there any other better NPM module?

Will saving logs in MySql database better option even though it requires a database call?

Need these logs to check for any API activity.

Comment: Ultimately, it depends. You probably won't want to log SQL issues to SQL, for example.

Comment: @NAVIN did you find any solution for it?